# c++ tree traversal depth

Tags: c++, tree

I try to traverse a tree, depth first.
Node has get_child() and get_sibling().

Here is my naive approch which obv. doesnt work:

```
int traverseTree(const Node *node)
{
    printf("index: %d \n", node->get_idx());
    const Node *child = node->get_child();
    const Node *sibling = node->get_sibling();

    if (child != NULL) {
        traverseTree(child);

    }
    else if (sibling != NULL)
    {
        traverseTree(sibling);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

here is how the tree is built: https://github.com/rggibson/open-pure-cfr/blob/master/betting_node.cpp#L137

Comment: I think we need to see your node structure.

Comment: I smell robo upvoters around! Someone has hot brew at hand, to cook them and becoming kinda delicate?

Comment: At a guess, I think you should remove the "else", but I can't be certain without seeing the rest of your code (preferably a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a minor mistake which does adverse effect...

According to your code you will traverse through child or traverse through siblings not both. So you need to traverse through both child node as well as siblings.

Here is the perfect code.

```
int traverseTree(const Node *node)
{
    printf("index: %d \n", node->get_idx());
    const Node *child = node->get_child();
    const Node *sibling = node->get_sibling();

    /*First traverse through child up to full depth*/
    if (child != NULL) {
        traverseTree(child);

    }
    /* Traverse through sibling up to its full depth*/
    if (sibling != NULL)
    {
        traverseTree(sibling);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will works only for binary tree. For non-binary tree you need to loop through children and siblings as it have more than one child and sibling.